# Force close message in tab app

Tags: java, android

I am making a tab app using this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html). When I run my app on device it gives me Force close message. Here is my main activity code and my logcat is below. I have no idea where am I making mistake. here is the code

```
public class TabLayoutActivity extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    //Artist Tab
    intent = new Intent(this, Artists.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artist", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

  //Songs
    intent = new Intent(this, Songs.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Songs", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

  //Albums
    intent = new Intent(this, Album.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artist", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
}
}
```

here is my logcat

```
05-28 19:16:51.421: D/dalvikvm(15189): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 43K, 50% free 2725K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 33ms
05-28 19:16:51.441: D/AndroidRuntime(15189): Shutting down VM
05-28 19:16:51.441: W/dalvikvm(15189): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
05-28 19:16:51.451: E/AndroidRuntime(15189): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 19:16:51.451: E/AndroidRuntime(15189): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zafar.tablayout/com.zafar.tablayout.TabLayoutActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'
05-28 19:16:51.451: E/AndroidRuntime(15189):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
05-28 19:16:51.451: E/AndroidRuntime(15189):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
05-28 19:16:51.451: E/AndroidRuntime(15189):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-28 19:16:51.451: E/AndroidRuntime(15189):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
05-28 19:16:51.451: E/AndroidRuntime(15189):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-28 19:16:51.451: E/AndroidRuntime(15189):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-28 19:16:51.451: E/AndroidRuntime(15189):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
05-28 19:16:51.451: E/AndroidRuntime(15189):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 19:16:51.451: E/AndroidRuntime(15189):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-28 19:16:51.451: E/AndroidRuntime(15189):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
05-28 19:16:51.451: E/AndroidRuntime(15189):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
05-28 19:16:51.451: E/AndroidRuntime(15189):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-28 19:16:51.451: E/AndroidRuntime(15189): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'
05-28 19:16:51.451: E/AndroidRuntime(15189):    at android.app.TabActivity.onContentChanged(TabActivity.java:105)
05-28 19:16:51.451: E/AndroidRuntime(15189):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:218)
05-28 19:16:51.451: E/AndroidRuntime(15189):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1663)
05-28 19:16:51.451: E/AndroidRuntime(15189):    at com.zafar.tablayout.TabLayoutActivity.onCreate(TabLayoutActivity.java:14)
05-28 19:16:51.451: E/AndroidRuntime(15189):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-28 19:16:51.451: E/AndroidRuntime(15189):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
05-28 19:16:51.451: E/AndroidRuntime(15189):    ... 11 more
05-28 19:16:57.256: I/Process(15189): Sending signal. PID: 15189 SIG: 9
```

**Update**

Here is my tabhost in main.xml

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tabHost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

**Second Update**

Logcat after changing tabHost to tabhost

```
05-28 19:47:56.271: I/Process(16575): Sending signal. PID: 16575 SIG: 9
05-28 19:47:58.381: D/dalvikvm(16782): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 46K, 50% free 2725K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 20ms
05-28 19:47:58.411: D/AndroidRuntime(16782): Shutting down VM
05-28 19:47:58.411: W/dalvikvm(16782): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
05-28 19:47:58.411: E/AndroidRuntime(16782): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 19:47:58.411: E/AndroidRuntime(16782): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zafar.tablayout/com.zafar.tablayout.TabLayoutActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your TabHost must have a TabWidget whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabs'
05-28 19:47:58.411: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
05-28 19:47:58.411: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
05-28 19:47:58.411: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-28 19:47:58.411: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
05-28 19:47:58.411: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-28 19:47:58.411: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-28 19:47:58.411: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
05-28 19:47:58.411: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 19:47:58.411: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-28 19:47:58.411: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
05-28 19:47:58.411: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
05-28 19:47:58.411: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-28 19:47:58.411: E/AndroidRuntime(16782): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your TabHost must have a TabWidget whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabs'
05-28 19:47:58.411: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at android.widget.TabHost.setup(TabHost.java:114)
05-28 19:47:58.411: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at android.widget.TabHost.setup(TabHost.java:163)
05-28 19:47:58.411: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at android.app.TabActivity.onContentChanged(TabActivity.java:109)
05-28 19:47:58.411: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:218)
05-28 19:47:58.411: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1663)
05-28 19:47:58.411: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at com.zafar.tablayout.TabLayoutActivity.onCreate(TabLayoutActivity.java:14)
05-28 19:47:58.411: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-28 19:47:58.411: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
05-28 19:47:58.411: E/AndroidRuntime(16782):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `main.xml`, what is the ID of the TabHost?

It must be `android:id="@android:id/tabhost"`.

**Edit**

Your `TabWidget` must be defined as:

```
<TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

It's actually quite easy to see from the logcat: "Your TabHost must have a TabWidget whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabs'".

It would be easier if you posted your entire xml layout file, so we can see all possible errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the right id to the tabhost in main.xml?

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

The problem you misscalled the id, you have to use @android, just replace the line

```
android:id="@+id/tabHost"
```

with

```
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
```

Comment: I did then I got this error `error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@android:id/tabHost').`

Comment: @al0ne I'm not sure if the id is case-sensitive, did you tried using tabhost instead tabHost

Comment: I changed it. Now I got new error. Could you see my update above. I posted logcat in second update

Answer (score 0):

you must import your package name.R;  like

> import package.R;

and also insted of this way i'll prefer use this to get tab host. some thing like.     `

> TabHost th = (TabHost)findViewbyid(R.id.tabhost);

and carry on it ill help

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

The problem was in main.xml file. I should have used `@android:id/idname` everywhere in main.xml. But I used `@+id/idname` which is wrong. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Some main things u need to follow..

1.Need to give permission in manifestfile.
  2.some time layout height and width are too large when u compare with the current emulator or screen